DataGrid Button in TemplateColumn needs 2 different DataContext
I have a DataGrid with a bindet ItemsSource. One Column has a Button in it, there I need the CommandParameter from the itemsSource but the Command from the Pages DataContext. I hope you understand my Problem and can help me solve it...
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:MemberOverviewPageViewModel x:Name="ViewModel"/>
</Page.DataContext>

<ui:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding MemberCollection}">
            <ui:DataGrid.Columns>
                      [...]
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ui:Button Content="Edit" CommandBindings="{Binding Method_From_Page_DataContext}" CommandParameter="{Binding ID_From_ItemSource }">
                                <ui:Button.Command></ui:Button.Command>
                            </ui:Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </ui:DataGrid.Columns>
        </ui:DataGrid>

public partial class MemberOverviewPageViewModel:ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty] public ObservableCollection<Member> _memberCollection = new()
    {
        new Member()
        {
            Name = "Doe",
            GivenName = "John",
            Birtday = new DateTime(1987, 12, 3),
            ID = 1
        }
    };

    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task EditUser(int ID)
    {
        // Some Magic happens here...
    }
}


This is a rather easy problem to fix, declare template with your button above your data grid and use a Binding Proxy to carry over the data context of parent. Or keep it as it is and use Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ui:DataGrid}, Path=DataContext.Method_From_Page_DataContext}" and see if that works
